# Python - Loading a source script

Tags: python

I am brand new to python and I'm using IDLE. However, as I learn, it is very tedious to retype an entire class over and over again at the prompt while I work out small syntax errors.

I would love to simply write a `.py` script in notepad++ and load it from the IDLE prompt. How is this done?

*I'm using Windows not UNIX/Linux or Mac*

Comment: Consider installing an alternate Python shell, like [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/install.html) which allows you to edit previous commands (hit the up arrow) in addition to many other features.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You can do the same in IDLE (I think previous command is bound to Crtl+P). But an alternate editor still wouldn't resolve the issue that the OP doesn't want to have to insert the command to run every time.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr if that editor was Sublime Text, it would :) but your point is valid.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid At some stage I rebound previous command to Crtl+P in my IDLE. Its a surprisingly good editor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In IDLE**, <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will create a new python file that you can edit your code in. When you click <kbd>F5</kbd> it will prompt you to save the file, which you can save anywhere and then will execute the file.

Each time you edit, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the newly updated file.